# Rails: Posting from a form to a M:M table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

On the group index page I display a listing of group discussions and a form to create a new discussion.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discussions
end

class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Controller:

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @discussion = current_user.discussions.build({group_id: @group.id}) if logged_in?
    @discussions = @group.discussions
  end

  def create
    @discussion = current_user.discussions.build(discussion_params)
    if @discussion.save
      flash[:success] = "Discussion started."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  private

    def discussion_params
      params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

My form is as follows.

```
<%= form_for([@group, @discussion]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Start a discussion..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This works correctly however when a form is submitted the row is recorded without the group_id. I suspect the problem lies in the way I am building the discussion object in the create action however am unsure of how to do it differently.

```
Started POST "/groups/635601/discussions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-22 15:16:07 +1000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by DiscussionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tJWJQKb6NcS1EAaeeLramzQp82xf4hLrXt+UTzKQo8+i1ePoNLYr8jXYSgBLpSxNvoPOAfNxnim1Ln6fKJ0uiw==", "discussion"=>{"title"=>"Test1", "content"=>"Test2"}, "commit"=>"Post", "group_id"=>"635601"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 406]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "discussions" ("title", "content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "Test1"], ["content", "Test2"], ["user_id", 406], ["created_at", "2015-06-22 05:16:07.883843"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-22 05:16:07.883843"]]
   (13.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 81ms (ActiveRecord: 15.5ms)
```

I can see in the params collection that the group_id is on there but outside of the hash.

Comment: Please post your `params log`

Comment: Post your `new` method of controller!

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ci5uQOPaRlef6HcCYln/Ks6Ykraqqms8ysCLAa3sG1NiuyzTXLcM3j8CbJKexnqRT4h1hV79uyQ2Jv3FXsf9Bw==", "discussion"=>{"title"=>"Test1", "content"=>"Test2"}, "commit"=>"Post", "group_id"=>"635601"}

Comment: There is no new action. The object is built in the Index action.

Comment: You shouldn't update your post with the suggestions given.

Comment: The @ missing from before group.id was a typo. I just corrected the post after you pointed it out. I've taken the :group_id out of the params however I had it in earlier and it made no difference.

Comment: Please update your post with the full log.

Comment: Did you tried adding `@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])` to your create action and doing like `@discussion.group_id = @group.id`?

Comment: Hi Pravan, this did work however it does feel a bit clunky. I am keep to know if this is the "Rails Way" or if there is a better system. I note this solution works even with :group_id removed from params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, you need to tweak your `create` action like this in order to save `group_id`.

```
def create
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
@discussion = current_user.discussions.build(discussion_params)
@discussion.group_id = @group.id
 if @discussion.save
   flash[:success] = "Discussion started."
   redirect_to root_url
 end
end
```

***OR***

You can add a `hidden_field` in your `form_for` to save `group_id` like this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @group.id %>
```

In this case your `create` action would be like this

```
def create
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
@discussion = current_user.discussions.build(discussion_params)
 if @discussion.save
   flash[:success] = "Discussion started."
   redirect_to root_url
 end
end
```

And you need to add `group_id` to your `discussion_params` as well

```
def discussion_params
  params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :content, :group_id)
end
```

And, yes it is completely Rails way of doing.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for all your help. I have implemented the former as I don't feel comfortable creating a hidden field if not required. With a hidden field I would not require "@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])" would I?

Comment: @user1567212 You should require it in order to add value to the `hidden_field` i.e, `:value => @group.id`.

Comment: @user1567212 Sorry. I guess you don't need it.